# Python how to pass the var/value from the command button and use it in an if

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

How can i pass the var/value from the command button into a def and implementing it in the if inside the def *ChangConfWI* to get the desired value?

Having 3 buttons i need that depending on the button you click it gets a specific var inside the def *ChangConfWI*, for that im using a if statement

```
global ocppurl, tiporeq, headers, payload, timeoutvar
ocppurl = "http://oxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx-ws/rest/xxxxx/"
headers = "{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'stat': '00012'}"
timeoutvar = 30

def ChangConfWI(var):
    if var == wi:
        tiporeq = "onething"
        payload = json.dumps({0})
    elif var == wik:
        tiporeq = "something"
        payload = json.dumps({1})
    elif var == vliv:
        tiporeq = "congo"
        payload = json.dumps({2})

    pedido = str(ocppurl + tiporeq) + "\n\n" + str(headers) + "\n\n" + str(payload) + "\n\n" + "Timeout:" + str(timeoutvar)
    reqinp.delete('1.0', END)
    reqinp.insert(tk.INSERT, pedido)



ttk.Button(frmbut2, width="20", text="without inputs", command=ChangConfWI(wi)).grid(column=0,row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Button(frmbut2, width="20", text="with invalid key", command=ChangConfWI(wik)).grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10,                                                                                 pady=10)
ttk.Button(frmbut2, width="20", text="with valid key & invalid value", command=ChangConfWI(vliv)).grid(column=0, row=2,
                                                                                                    padx=10, pady=10)
```

Comment: What is your code trying to accomplish? I don't know your end goal.

Comment: Use a `lambda` in the `command` argument.

Comment: As Barmar said: change `command=ChangConfWI(wi)` to `command=lambda: ChangConfWI(wi)`

Comment: thank you all, made that several time in this project and totally blank

Answer (score 0):

```
ttk.Button(frmbut2, width="20", text="without inputs", command=lambda: ChangConfWI(1)).grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
```